# signed bit extension of offset in MIPS

Tags: mips

In MIPS  instructions like 
       LW $1, 2($2)
 I know that why do we need to extend the offset from 16 bits to 32 bits but my question is that why do we  extend the sign it like 
11111111111111111111111111111000 for -8
why not simply 
00000000000000000000000000001000

Answer (score 1):

In MIPS we use signed 2's complement, check this it will make it all clear:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Nevertheless to answer your question, the sign of a number in 2's complement is dictated by its most significant bit, 0 for positive, 1 for negative, if you have a negative number therefore you extend with 1's, if positive with 0's

Hope this helps =)